# Como deixar a imagem a esquerda e o texto ao lado

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Boa Tarde, estou praticando flexbox utilizando o site da IGN Brasil como inspiração e quero fazer algo assim: [image: exemplo]

Onde a imagem fica de um lado e o conteudo fica ao lado dela, tentei utilizar `display: flex` mas fica meio zoado.

**Codigo HTML**

```
<section class="noticias">
    <div>
    <h2>Final Fantasy 7 Rekam: Red XIII nao sera jogavel</h2>
        <p>Primeira parte da recriação do clássico de Playstation não permitira que <br>
        controlemos um heroi importante</p>            
        <img src="https://sm.ign.com/t/ign_br/news/f/final-fant/final-fantasy-7-remake-red-xiii-is-not-a-playable-character_jvpt.280.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</section>
```

*Parte CSS esta vazia*

Comment: Não entendi, o que é "zoado"? O Zoado para vc pode não ser o zoado para outras pessoas, explica melhor o que vc quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ficar alinhado da imagem, precisa deixar o elemento `IMG` e o elemento `DIV`ao mesmo nível, após isso basta usar o `display:flex` normal, usei o `justify-content: flex-start` para forçar ficar no início.

```css
.noticias{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.noticias img,
.noticias div{
    padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<section class="noticias">
    <img src="https://sm.ign.com/t/ign_br/news/f/final-fant/final-fantasy-7-remake-red-xiii-is-not-a-playable-character_jvpt.280.jpg" alt="">
    <div>
        <h2>Final Fantasy 7 Rekam: Red XIII nao sera jogavel</h2>
        <p>Primeira parte da recriação do clássico de Playstation não permitira que <br>controlemos um heroi importante</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

#### Referência: [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)